# ag-grid angular 5 export hidde, columns

Tags: angular5, ag-grid

I am working on a export feature for my ag-grid columns on angular 5

here is the code for my columns :

```
columnDefs = [{  
  headerName:'',
  field:'',
  pinned:true,
  headerCheckboxSelection:true,
  headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly:true,
  width:42,
  checkboxSelection:true
}, {  
  headerName:'Actions',
  field:'_id.$oid',
  cellRenderer:'viewModalRenderer',
  pinned:true
}, {  
  headerName:'Status',
  field:'status'
}, {  
  headerName:'Category',
  field:'category',
  cellRenderer:'viewCetegoryRenderer',
  width:120,
  editable:true,
  hide:true
}, {  
  headerName:'Created',
  field:'created',
  editable:true,
  filter:'agDateColumnFilter'
}, {  
  headerName:'Price',
  field:'price',
  filter:'agNumberColumnFilter',
  width:120,
  editable:true
}];
```

I am calling this function to export

```
onBtnExport() {
  let params = {}
  this.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv(params);
}
```

How to include the Category column marked as hide: true in my export ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   exportCsv() {       
    var excelParams = {
        columnKeys: ['firstName', 'middleName','lastName', 'dob'],
        allColumns: false,
        fileName: 'Student List.csv',
        skipHeader: false,
        customHeader: 'Student List' + '\n',
        customFooter: '\n \n Total No.Of Students :' + this.gridOptions.api.getModel().getRowCount() + ' \n'
    }
    this.gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv(excelParams);
}
```

Define the columns to be displayed in columnKeys